# Rsync ssh file transfer through expect showing error when executed through while loop in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, expect

My program needs **automatic file transfer** to  many remote systems. So tried using expect for RSYNC SSH file transfer. While I run the **.ex** file through terminal providing the necessary inputs or through a simple bash script containing passing values, it worked fine.

But I want to call the .ex file to transfer file through RSYNC to more than 100 machines after checking from database, so I need to run the script through some loops, populating the variables dynamically...

MY .ex file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set pass [lindex $argv 0]
set server [lindex $argv 1]
set name [lindex $argv 2]
set addr [lindex $argv 3]


set timeout -1

spawn rsync -e "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ${addr}  ${name}@${server}:/home/deba/


expect {
-re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
send "yes\n"
exp_continue
#look for the password prompt
}

"*?assword:*" {
send ${pass}
send "\n"
interact
#The expect command will now return
}
}
```

My Bash script that shows error:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /home/deba/content_sync/test/result_remote/sync_Dest_List.txt  | while read  line2
do

java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar Remote_sync_pw_ip_reciever $line2

cat /home/deba/content_sync/test/result_remote/sync_Dest_List.txt  | while read  line

# this folder contains the arguments for password and server IP  separated by space
do
IFS=" " read var1 var2 <<< "$line"



./rsync1.ex $var1 $var2 $line2 /home/deba/cron.sh 

done
done
```

Errors Generated :

```
spawn rsync -e ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  /home/deba/cron.sh@deba:/home/deba/
skipping directory .
rsync: mkdir "/home/deba/cron.sh@deba:/home/deba" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

But a simple calling from the bash code not showing any error:

```
#!/bin/bash

./rsync1.ex rups78 10.129.30.44 deba /home/deba/cron.sh
```

Please suggest the solution to completely automate the whole file transfer process without the need of any human interference...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Put `set -x` right before your `./rsync1.ex ...` line, and `set -x` after it. This will show in visually unambiguous format how the command is executed. See how it compares to your simple calling invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to figure out what you are trying to do, but one simple advise would be to use ssh keys for password-less logon's. This alone have two advantages:

- no need for passwords stored in plain text
- simpler login procedure from your scipt, you will most likely not need the expect part at all.

Of cause this requires that you have privileges to install the ssh keys on the remote server. Lets assume you have that. Then the setup job is something along these points:

1. generate public keys on local machines: `ssh-keygen -t dsa`
2. copy the generated `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` files to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine

In step 2. you will have to put the content of multiple files into one file, simply append them together.

Comment: thnks for your reply.. the confusion is I dont know the receivers have ssh installed or not, In my case I am developing a web apps by which users can register and get the updates periodically through rsync and cron